# strtok() command with Serial communicaton

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming

After I take a char* variable from serial communication, I use `strtok` to split variables with " ". But when I do that it acts like there is a " " after every character. I dont know why. How can I fix this ?

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  char* a = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
  char* c = a3;
  char* b;
  b = strtok(c, " ");
  while (b != NULL) {
    Serial.println(b);
    b = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

outcome:

```
The
quick
brown
...
```

This parsing code works perfectly, until I take it from serial ports. Serial code here, like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define bRSerial 9600
#define bRmY 9600

char vD[45];
int i = 0;

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(bRSerial);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
  mySerial.begin(bRmY);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    //Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    vD[i]=mySerial.read();
    i++;
    if (i = 46) {
      char* a = vD;
      char* b;
      
      b = strtok(a, " ");
      while (b != NULL) {
        Serial.println(b);
        b = strtok(NULL, " ");
      }
      i=0;
    }
  }
}
```

outcome:

```
T
h
e
q
u
i
c
k
b
r
o
w
...
```

Is there a way to fix this? i need to get it from serial and split on " ".

Comment: `if ( i == 46 ) {`

Comment: yep that was it.  :D simply 1 mistake that i couldnt see thanks.

Comment: is this how you plan to use it or only a test? it would be simpler to detect the delimiter when it is read

Comment: i dont know how to use it simplier.

Comment: if this is not only a strtok test, the you do not need strtok. read in char c, and if `c == ' '`, print vD and reset i to 0 else `vD[i] = c`

Comment: and I do not see where you set the terminating 0 of `vD` a.k.a. `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only a syntax typo. the condition should be `if ( i == 46 ) {`

if this is not only a strtok test, the you do not need strtok. read in char c, and if `c == ' '`, print vD and reset i to 0

and I do not see where you set the terminating 0 of `vD` a.k.a. `a`

Answer (score 0):

As @Juraz mentioned, in the case you have a typo. Also I'd have suggestions as one who had spent a while coding reading process in terminal. When you need to read something from a serial port it is good to use the `while()` loop, instead of `if()`, so I recommend changing:

```
while (mySerial.available()) {
  //Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  vD[i]=mySerial.read();
  i++;
  if (i == 46) {
    char* a = vD;
    char* b;

    b = strtok(a, " ");
    while(b != NULL) {
      Serial.println(b);
      b = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    i=0;
  }
}
```

Comment: the `if` is in `loop()`